# To fetch a complete sentence containing the search key in it

Tags: php

I have to fetch a complete sentence from the given string in which the desired character must exist. Like say I have a search Key "**different topic**"and i am searching it in "**Our community is defined by a specific set of topics in the help center; please stick to those topics and avoid asking for opinions or open-ended discussion. If your question is about the site itself, ask on our meta-discussion site. If you’re looking for a different topic, it might be covered on another Stack Exchange site.**"

After my search I want it to return as complete sentence "***If you’re looking for a *different topic*, it might be covered on another Stack Exchange site.***"

This is the complete sentence  containing my search key too.

I have used the following for this but not getting the proper output:

```
substr($fp, strpos($fp, $search_string) - 100, 200).
```

This is all in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really cannot do this using `substr()` but you can with a little regex:

```
[A-Z][^\\.;]*(different topic)[^\\.;]*
```

Here is an [EXAMPLE](https://regex101.com/r/BoQjdm/1)

If you need the period at the end of the sentence, modify the regex slightly to remove the period from the character match at the end of the phrase, `[^\\;]` instead of `[^\\.;]`

```
[A-Z][^\\.;]*(different topic)[^\\;]*
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with this following code:-

Instead of this:- 
substr($fp, strpos($fp, $search_string) - 100, 200);

I have used following to fetch the sentence with complete words containing my search key:-

```
 $sentences = explode('.',$fp);
 $subString = "";
 foreach($sentences as $sentence) {
    if(false !== stripos($sentence,$search_string)){
      $subString = trim($sentence) . "\n";
    }   
 }
```

and this helped me to fetch the proper result.